# App without splash screen (Default.png) is a reject reason?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, splash-screen, appstore-approval

In a universal app, you have to add 6 splash images named Default.png.

**320 x 480** for non-retina iphone

**640 x 960** for retina iphone

**768 x 1024** for non-retina iPad-portrait

**1536 x 2048** for retina iPad-portrait

**1024 x 768** for non-retina iPad-landscape

**2048 x 1536** for retina iPad-landscape

What if I'm fine with that black screen displayed when you don't provide any splash screen image.

Does Apple reject apps just because of this? I couldn't find anything.

Do I have to create 6 useless black png's and add them to the project?

Comment: The idea is to _not_ simply make it black.  You should show an image showing the default UI.  So instead of a black screen while you're loading, users immediately see something (feedback)... otherwise users might question why the screen is black (did the app crash?) and immediately press "Home" and "Delete" your app.  And while you might not "care", your writing this app for yourself or your users? ;)

Comment: Actually I know what splash screen's are used for. Just in this app splash screen has to be black. I'm asking "How can I go to Iceland", and you are responding "Don't go there, it is too cold, there are warmer places in the world." Thanks anyway.

Comment: This seems like a very legitimate question to me.  What if your app is such that it launches immediately in order to show a custom splash complete with loading animation?  Would be silly to still have to specify splash screens then.  However, for MOST use cases, the splash screen model is fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[iOS Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW5) says explicitly:

> To enhance the user’s experience at application launch, you **must** provide at least one launch image.

The launch image is there to be displayed while your app is loading and have to look like the first screen of your app:

> A launch image looks very similar to the first screen your application displays.

So yes, you have to provide launch images, and even if you are happy with just a black launch screen, this is not enough unless the first screen in your app is actually just a black screen?

Comment: I'm expected to play an intro video at the opening. First frames of the video is black, so splash screen has to be black in order to make it compatible with the video.

Comment: It is my bad that I couldn't find that iOS Human Interface Guidelines about splash screens, using Google. Thank you.

Comment: Ok. An extension question to the OP's question. If my app is landscape only, what should I supply for the launch images? Landscape only launch images suffice?

Comment: No, they want them both even if your app is designed for only one orientation.

Comment: It look like they fixed it. Application Loader / Xcode Organizer no longer complains about this issue.

Comment: Updated [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/launch-screen/) link